# Windows XP remove certain abilities for groups

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy

In my environment, I want to prevent temporary users(guests and such), from shutting down the computer. From within Windows.

I would have thought this option would be listed in the USER/Groups Management section, but it is not. Or I didn't find it.
I've checked the group policies too, but I didn't find it.

How can I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to prevent users from shutting down or restarting XP and Vista](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/how-to-prevent-users-from-shutting-down-or-restarting/) :

> - Type gpedit.msc in run dialog box [ WIN KEY + R ]
> - This will open Group Policy Editor. Now there are two things in it,
>     Computer Configuration and User
>     Configuration
> - Click on User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu
>     and Task Bar
> - Now look for “remove and prevent access to shutdown command”
> - Double Click and Enable it.
> - Exit the group policy editor.
>
> This setting removes the Shut Down
>   option from the Start menu and
>   disables the Shut Down button on the
>   Windows Security dialog box, which
>   appears when you press CTRL+ALT+DEL.

**EDIT**

These settings are applicable to all users except administrators.
You'll need to create non-Administrator accounts for the other users.
You can restart the computer and log in as Administrator to change it back.

See also this article:
[How to prevent shutdown of a Windows XP computer](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/xp-prevent-shutdown/)

Comment: Aha, that's it. I find the choice of words by windows to be a little strange though. Probably why I didn't find it.

Comment: When I enabled this, it seems to be in place for every single account on the system. I want this to be limited to the guests only. Is that possible?

Comment: See my edit above.